# Computer Vision System Toolbox & GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst, vision

I am using Computer Vision System Toolbox in Matlab to grabb images from two cameras simultaneously, I want to create an Graphical User Interface which include the picture grabbing from two cameras into two axis. The problem is I don't know how to create GUI with axis while using Computer Vision System Toolbox. Can you help me or provide me an matlab code for creating GUI using Computer Vision System toolbox to grabb images from camera in real time.

kind regards

Comment: Hi! could you please show us what you have tried so far first?

Comment: I have not tried, because I am new user, i want an example for start

Comment: how do you upload matlab code into stackoverflow forum

Comment: @user3636800 SO works dofferent of anormal forum. Here you need a specific question yo get a specific answer. This is not the rigth place to ask for code or tutorials. :)

Answer (score 0):

The only features of the Computer Vision System Toolbox itself that can be considered GUI components are `vision.VideoPlayer` and `vision.DeployableVideoPlayer` for playing videos. You can also use functions like `insertObjectAnnotation`, `insertShape`, `insertMarker`, `insertText` to draw text and graphics into the video frames.

However, there are GUI components in the rest of MATLAB. For playing multiple video streams inside a custom GUI, take a look at this [example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/video-display-in-a-custom-user-interface.html)